# Why am I getting this Django NoReverseMatch error?

Tags: django

I'm getting Django's dreaded "NoReverseMatch" error and I can't see the problem.  I believe I'm doing everything correctly.

When I try to go to the music application's home page at 127.0.0.1:8000/music/ I get the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /music/
Reverse for 'album-delete' with arguments '(",)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['music/album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+/delete/$']
```

Here are my urls:

```
# app/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
  path('music/', include('music.urls')),
]

# music/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'music'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('album/add/', views.AlbumCreate.as_view(), name='album-add'),
    path('album/<int:pk>/', views.AlbumUpdate.as_view(), name='album-update'),
    # Problem is with this url pattern:
    path('album/<int:pk>/delete/', views.AlbumDelete.as_view(), name='album-delete'),
]
```

Here is the template calling the delete url:

```
  # music/index.html
  <form action="{% url 'music:album-delete' album.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="album_id" value="{{ album.id }}">
    <button type="submit"></button>
  </form>
```

Here is the class-based view to delete an album:

```
# music/views.py
class AlbumDelete(generic.DeleteView):
    model = Album
    success_url = 'music:index'
```

The error is triggered by the form's action attribute because if I just set the action to blank, the error goes away.

```
<form action="" method="post">  <!-- No error -->
```

Comment: if music/index.html does not have a `album` object passed to it, album.id is empty.  This breaks the url pattern.  Additionally. the albun_id is not needed in both the url & the form to figure out which one to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Only render the album delete form if there is a single `album` instance passed to the template. To use the DeleteView, The album pk / id should be in the url params, and is not needed in the form.

**urls.py**

```
path('album/<int:pk>/delete/', views.AlbumDelete.as_view(), name='album-delete'),
```

**template example:**

```
# music/index.html
{% if album %}
  <form action="{% url 'music:album-delete' album.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit"></button>
  </form>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This prevents the error from occurring but results in another error "Generic detail view AlbumDelete must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf."  This makes sense as the class-based view doesn't know what it's supposed to be deleting.

Comment: I just noticed this is using the built-in Generic Delete view.  I updated the answer, hope this helps